# C - Get File Bytes as Unsigned Int

Tags: c

I need the bytes of a BIN file converted to a unsigned int, in this format (JavaScript):

```
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000000), 0x00000be9);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000004), 0x90909000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000008), 0x90909090);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000000c), 0x90909090);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000010), 0x0082b955);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000014), 0x8948c000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000018), 0x415741e5);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000001c), 0x41554156);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000020), 0x83485354);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000024), 0x320f18ec);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000028), 0x89d58949);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000002c), 0x64b948c0);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000030), 0x77737069);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000034), 0x49000000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000038), 0x4120e5c1);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000003c), 0x000200bc);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000040), 0xc5094900);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000044), 0xd0b58d4d);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000048), 0x49ffcf14);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000004c), 0x8a509d8d);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000050), 0x81490003);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000054), 0x030b50c5);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000058), 0x868d4901);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000005c), 0x001d18d0);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000060), 0x00c68149);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000064), 0x48001d17);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000068), 0x48c04589);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000006c), 0xad0000a1);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000070), 0x000000de);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000074), 0x45894800);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000078), 0x888948c8);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000007c), 0x000000e0);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000080), 0xf080c748);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000084), 0x00000000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000088), 0x48000000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000008c), 0x00f880c7);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000090), 0x00000000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000094), 0x1aeb0000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000098), 0x00841f0f);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000009c), 0x00000000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000a0), 0x4cee894c);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000a4), 0x8b48ff89);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000a8), 0xd0ffc045);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000ac), 0x01ec8341);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000b0), 0x02ba2774);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000b4), 0x4c000000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000b8), 0x80bfee89);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000bc), 0x41000001);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000c0), 0x8d48d6ff);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000c4), 0x00006f3d);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000c8), 0xc7894900);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000cc), 0x31c68948);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000d0), 0x4cd3ffc0);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000d4), 0x75c87d39);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000d8), 0xe43145c7);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000dc), 0xc8758b48);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000e0), 0x5f3d8d48);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000e4), 0x31000000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000e8), 0x0fd3ffc0);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000ec), 0x0000441f);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000f0), 0x0000a148);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000f4), 0x0000dead);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000f8), 0x89440000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000000fc), 0x3d8d48e6);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000100), 0x0000005c);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000104), 0x20148b4a);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000108), 0x08c48349);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000010c), 0xd3ffc031);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000110), 0x80fc8149);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000114), 0x75000001);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000118), 0x3d8d48d7);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000011c), 0x00000060);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000120), 0xd3ffc031);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000124), 0x18c48348);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000128), 0x415bc031);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000012c), 0x415d415c);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000130), 0x5d5f415e);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000134), 0x909090c3);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000138), 0x6f6c6c41);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000013c), 0x30203a63);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000140), 0x786c2578);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000144), 0x624f000a);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000148), 0x7463656a);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000014c), 0x6d754420);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000150), 0x78302070);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000154), 0x0a786c25);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000158), 0x00000000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000015c), 0x00000000);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000160), 0x6265443c);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000164), 0x203e6775);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000168), 0x656a624f);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000016c), 0x2b207463);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000170), 0x25783020);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000174), 0x3a783330);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000178), 0x25783020);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000017c), 0x000a786c);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000180), 0x6265443c);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000184), 0x203e6775);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000188), 0x7473754a);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000018c), 0x726f4620);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000190), 0x7468203a);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000194), 0x3a737074);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000198), 0x77772f2f);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000019c), 0x6f792e77);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000001a0), 0x62757475);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000001a4), 0x6f632e65);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000001a8), 0x61772f6d);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000001ac), 0x3f686374);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000001b0), 0x4a563d76);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000001b4), 0x6d6c5247);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000001b8), 0x4c6c6133);
    p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x000001bc), 0x00000a59);
```

I assume the first hex in `add32` is the count, and the last hex are the bytes of the file. I've made a small concept for this, but it doesn't work correctly. *Note this code is not for production purposes.*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("loader", "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int s = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);

    FILE *o = fopen("loader.txt", "wb");

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < s / 4; i++) {
        unsigned int u;
        fread(&u, sizeof(u), 1, f);
        fprintf(o, "p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x%08x), 0x%08x);\n", i, u);
    }

    fclose(o);
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

That code *partially* works and outputs the following:

```
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000000), 0x00067be9);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000001), 0x0f2e6600);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000002), 0x0000841f);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000003), 0x90000000);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000004), 0x000082b9);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000005), 0x0f5741c0);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000006), 0xd1894832);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000007), 0xc1485641);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000008), 0x554120e1);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000009), 0x41c10948);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000000a), 0x8d485554);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000000b), 0xcf14d0a9);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000000c), 0x894953ff);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000000d), 0xec8348f6);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000000e), 0x858d4848);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000000f), 0x00286cf0);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000010), 0x50998d48);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000011), 0x4800038a);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000012), 0x20244489);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000013), 0xd0a18d4c);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000014), 0x310005a9);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000015), 0x28bf48c0);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000016), 0x0926204b);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000017), 0x4c000000);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000018), 0x71b8ad8b);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x00000019), 0xd3ff01fe);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000001a), 0x8948c031);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000001b), 0x50bf48ee);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000001c), 0x0926204b);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000001d), 0xff000000);
p.write4(shellcode.add32(0x0000001e), 0x468b49d3);
```

The problem of this code is, it doesn't display the first hex (the `add32` one) correctly like the first code example. How do I make it so it is exactly like the first code example?

Any help is absolutely appreciated!

Comment: You need `(i * 4)` since it's the file offset and that's sizeof int32.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: @DaveS So if I understand you correctly I should do `for(i = 0; i * 4; i++) {`?

Comment: @Herohtar The output is javascript.

Comment: @J.Doe no do the `i*4` in the `printf`, not in the loop

Comment: @Pablo Oh I see, my bad. That works perfectly, thanks a ton!

Comment: Are you writing an exploit?

Comment: @FrancescoLaurita I'm not writing an exploit, just expanding a already existing script.